# Need help wrapping my brain around Leetcode 2. Add Two Numbers (Linked Lists problem)

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, iteration

I'm using [this problem](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbTdkNnVGYkNfd1psY190Nm5tUXVhMHg5NkFYd3xBQ3Jtc0ttdUtUa1NzUGM2TzRxVFZFcXZQLUJHc01Sb1B2RVBsY2tzZkFmcVY2WE1fZ2pjVzNKN0tKSVA1b1RMQVdIOUZfdm1pMEJndGt3bUxqWng4bFdUX0FIUWIxZTJ0X3VJTW9yekZNZGg5dTM2Q01MVHpkYw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fleetcode.com%2Fproblems%2Fadd-two-numbers%2F&v=IkuWJSYqFAw) as an example, but what I'm really having a hard time with has to do with my understanding of linked lists in general, and how we can build them iterably. Here is the problem:

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

```
Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4] 
Output: [7,0,8]

Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.
```

I'm trying to understand this guy's [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkuWJSYqFAw). My confusion lies with how he is constructing the linkedlist, `added`. He defines it in the beginning as a list node with one number, and doesn't do anything to it until the very end where he just returns it. How did this get built then?

I understand `current_node` is set to `added` at first. But while the loops are iterating, `current_node.next` keeps being updated -- wouldn't this just change `current_node.next`, and then we would end up with a linked list of length 2? Where the first value is the first node, `(l1.val + l2.val) % 10`, and then the second value would be the last  `(carry_over + l1.val + l2.val) % 10`? Of course I know that's not the case because he ends up getting the correct linked list, but I really can't wrap my head around it.

I guess I really don't understand how to iterativaly build a linked list. A simple explanation would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't want to watch a 20-minute video. Can you provide the timecode for the part that's confusing you?

Comment: Presumably somewhere he does `current_node = current_node.next`. This moves the `current_node` cursor to the next node in the list. He stops when he gets to the end and adds a new element.

Comment: Go to timecode 12:40, that's where he explains that he's updating the current node to the next node.

Answer (score 0):

`current_node` is initialised to reference the same node as `added` with this statement:

```
current_node = added
```

They now both reference the first (and at that time, the only) node of the final list.

We can picture that as follows:

```
 added  current_node
   │        │
┌──┴────────┴───┐
│ val: 4        │
│ next: None    │
└───────────────┘
```

The presenter explains at 9:00 in the video:

> As we loop through, we are going to be altering **each node** as we go along.

This "altering" also applies to the very first node, pictured above.

In the loop, `current_node.next` gets assigned a reference to a new node. An important insight here is that in the **first** iteration this means that `added.next` gets assigned that reference: the two are referencing the same node (in the first iteration), so the following statement (see 11:45 in video):

```
current_node.next = ListNode(val = (carry_over + l1.val + l2.val) % 10)
```

...will lead to this:

```
 added  current_node
   │        │
┌──┴────────┴───┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ val: 4        │     │ val: 9        │
│ next: ──────────────┤ next: None    │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘
```

And then `current_node = current_node.next` will move the reference to that new node:

```
 added                  current_node
   │                         │
┌──┴────────────┐     ┌──────┴────────┐
│ val: 4        │     │ val: 9        │
│ next: ──────────────┤ next: None    │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘
```

It is no surprise that `added` always references the **head** node of the new list, but a more important invariant is this one: at the start of each iteration `current_node` references the current **tail** node of that list. So any update of `current_node.next` will actually affect the list that has `added` as head node.